# How to fix org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException?

Tags: android, datetime, utc, datetime-parsing, threetenbp

I am converting UTC time into local time and I facing the error:

> org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Oct 17
>   06:12:19 GMT+05:30 2018' could not be parsed at index 20

Please say any other options or fix this solution..

This is my code, please check it:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String formattedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(UTC_time, formatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(formatter);
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: DateTimeFormatter formatter
                    = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String formattedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(UTC_time, formatter)
                    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                    .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .format(formatter);

Comment: this is my code please check it.

Comment: It's better to embed your (nicely-formatted and tidy) code in the body of your question (I just edited it).

Comment: Funny, on the backport I get an exception like yours, but the index mentioned is 23 (where it says `+05:30`), not 20 (where it says `GMT`).

Comment: Your code works with the built-in java.time on Java 1.8.0_66 and on jdk-11, but fails on the backport. Might it be a bug in the backport or non-backported feature?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
       DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

You can use this [link](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm) to find your pattern

Comment: Strange, according to the [project page](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-): *Zone names: This outputs the display name of the time-zone ID. If the count of letters is one, two or three, then the short name is output. If the count of letters is four, then the full name is output. Five or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.* If so, `z` or `zzz` are the same.

Comment: Got it, the relevant part is `Locale.ENGLISH` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44014746/4375327)).

Comment: @Amessihel let us know how

Comment: am trying this it not affected on my code. it also return org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon Oct 22 14:15:27 GMT+05:30 2018' could not be parsed at index 20

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems that your string may come from calling `toString` on an old-fashioned `java.util.Date` object. If this is the case, you may see if you can get hold on the `Date` object itself and convert it using `DateTimeUtils` (from ThreeTenABP) and save all trouble of parsing.

Second, your code works with the built in java.time on my desktop computer, and I don’t know why it doesn’t work with the backport. A possible fix for the backport is:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String inputString = "Wed Oct 17 06:12:19 GMT+05:30 2018";
    String formattedDate = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputString, formatter)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

On my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone this outputs:

> Wed Oct 17 02:42:19 GMT+02:00 2018

**EDIT:** While it doesn’t seem to be documented that the backport supports the `O` format pattern letter, the above works on ThreeTen Backport 1.3.6 on my Mac. The documented alternative is the following variant of the format pattern:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xxx yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
```

If you prefer a time zone abbreviation like `CEST` over the GMT offset, you may use your original formatter for formatting back into a string. The trick is that `OOOO` in the format pattern parses `GMT+05:30` and this style of GMT or UTC offset in general.

I have fixed another bug in your code: When you were parsing into a `LocalDateTime`, you lost the time zone or offset information from the string, which caused your time to be wrong. Specifically, when there was `GMT+05:30` in the string and you did `.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`, the time was off by 5 hours 30 minutes. Use an `OffsetDateTime` for parsing instead (if `z` for zone name had worked, you would have needed a `ZonedDateTime`).

**Link:** [Documentation of `org.threeten.bp:format.DateTimeFormatter` including the format pattern letters](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: it doesn't work for me... and I get error is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'O'

Comment: Sorry, I missed this important detail: the backport doesn’t support pattern letter `O`. There are other possible solutions, maybe less elegant. I will think again and revert here.

Comment: hey i need better solution to convert UTC time to local time...please say to save my days...

Comment: I believe I have solved it, @Balasundark. Please see my edit.

Comment: i am removing the timezone like this (Tue Oct 23 11:41:26 2018) ...and my code was working fine.

Comment: It sounds to me like a shaky solution if the GMT offset may be something else than what you expect. Good luck with it.